# Why function variable returns wrong calculation?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, math

I'm having an issue with accuracy of my code.
I made a function to calculate the Fibonacci series:

```
  function fibonacciseries(max_number, p, n) {
    if(p === undefined) { p = 0;}
    if(n === undefined) { n = 1;}
    if(n > max_number) { return 0; }
    console.log(n);
    return fibonacciseries(max_number, n, n + p)
    }
 fibonacciseries(3)
```

but when I run this code, `console.log(n);` shows:

```
1
1
2
3
```

I think result should be `1 1 2`, so I really cannot understand why such a thing happens. Running `fibonacciseries(4)` & `fibonacciseries(5)` are OK, so what is wrong in the case of `fibonacciseries(3)` ? How should I fix this ?

Comment: You're testing `n > max_number`. Did you mean `n >= max_number` to exclude `max_number` from the logged list?

Comment: yes, it is.it needs =

Comment: I get the impression you intend for `max_number` to be a count of how many numbers the function should log, but what it is actually doing is logging all Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to `max_number`. That is, `fibonacciseries(20)` doesn't log 20 numbers, it logs all Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to 20.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, you are right.but how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `max_number` to be a count of how many numbers the function should log, but what it is actually doing is logging all Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to `max_number`. That is, `fibonacciseries(20)` doesn't log 20 numbers, it logs all Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to 20. It's just a coincidence that `fibonacciseries(4)` & `fibonacciseries(5)` happen to produce the same result either way.

To fix this, don't compare `max_number` to `n`, just decrement `max_number` on each call and stop when it gets to zero. To make this a bit clearer I suggest renaming that argument:

```js
function fibonacciseries(count, p, n) {
  if(p === undefined) { p = 0;}
  if(n === undefined) { n = 1;}
  if(count <= 0) { return 0; }
  console.log(n);
  return fibonacciseries(count - 1, n, n + p)
}

console.log("Count of 3:");
fibonacciseries(3);
console.log("Count of 5:");
fibonacciseries(5);
console.log("Count of 7:");
fibonacciseries(7);
```

Answer (score 1):

check the `n>=max_number` not `n>max_number`. Try the below updated code

```js
function fibonacciseries(max_number, p, n) {
    if(p === undefined) { p = 0;}
    if(n === undefined) { n = 1;}
    if(n >= max_number) { return 0; }
    console.log(n);
    return fibonacciseries(max_number, n, n + p)
    }
 fibonacciseries(3)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.When I run the codes `fibonacciseries(5)`,only 1 1 2 3 is shown.What is wrong??